# AWS::Events::Rule Input for target is not a valid JSON text

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-event-bridge, sam

I have the following resource in my SAM template.yml:

```yaml
MetricsRule:
  Type: AWS::Events::Rule
  Properties:
    Name: MetricsRule
    Description: Puts metrics to the CloudWatch log group
    EventBusName: !FindInMap [LambdaConfig, !Ref stage, eventBusName]
    EventPattern:
      detail:
        status:
          - GENERATED
    State: !FindInMap [LambdaConfig, !Ref stage, eventEnabled]
    Targets:
      - Id: LogGroupTarget
        Arn: !Sub "arn:aws:logs:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:log-group:${LogGroup}"
        InputTransformer:
          InputPathsMap:
            customer-id: $.detail.customerId
            destination-type: $.detail.destinationType
            provider-id: $.detail.providerId
          InputTemplate: '"cusId = <customer-id> - <destination-type> for <provider-id>"'
```

If I try to deploy this stack it fails with the exception `Input for target LogGroupTarget is not a valid JSON text.`

**UPD:**

If I put `InputTemplate` as `'{"message":"cusId = <customer-id> - <destination-type> for <provider-id>"}'` it will work. But, in the documentation, examples and even in the placeholder of the field in UI it stands that `Input Template: A string containing placeholders which will be filled with values defined in Input Paths e.g. "The state of Instance <instance> is <state>"`

Is there any option to specify `InputTemplate` as a string?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I hope author found answer.
But just to have answer here too.
This should work:

```
  InputTemplate: |
    "cusId = <customer-id> - <destination-type> for <provider-id>"
```

More information is here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-events-rule-inputtransformer.html